# Windows loses internet connection ... intermittently

Tags: windows-10, networking, vpn, dns

## Behavior

Internet disconnects intermittently:

[image]

Often, hitting (Ctrl+) F5 a bunch of times, disabling/enabling different connections, and other such actions, temporarily "solves" the issue. However, the problem comes back more and more frequently, and after about an hour of use, this sort of action no longer solves anything and a reboot is the only way to get back on the internet.

## Observations

After lots of trial and error, I'm suspecting some sort of DNS issue... What's got me totally stumped however, is the following observations:

- When "disconnected", I can sometimes:

  - `ping google.com` from WSL2, but not from CMD.exe
  - `ping google.com` from CMD.exe, but not from WSL2
- When "connected", I can sometimes:

  - not `ping google.com` from WSL2 or CMD.exe
- I can sometimes `ping 8.8.8.8` but not `ping google.com`
- Connectivity behaves *very* inconsistently; when I'm connected to VPN, disconnecting sometimes helps, sometimes not. When connected to WiFi, switching to wired sometimes helps, sometimes not...
- Often, when my browser claims I'm disconnected, Zoom/Spotify/etc. continues as normal. Not always, though...

## Stuff I've tried

- *Network Reset*, several times.
- Uninstalled/reinstalled ExpressVPN/Wireguard
- Disabled IP6 in all connections, to no avail
- Disabling/removing all network connections, except one.
- Physically remove the PiHole from the network, reconfiguring my router to match that setup, followed by `ipconfig /flushdns` on the problem machine
- Pulling the wire from the GBit ethernet port and connecting over WiFi (or vice versa) seems to have an effect (reconnects the machine), but only temporarily (so, not likely a hardware problem with either card)
- Update drivers (via Window Update)
- Completely disable Windows Firewall
- Disconnections happen in Edge, Firefox and Chrome (not a browser problem. Also, I never use Edge, so that's basically pristine)
- When disconnected, all other machines & devices on the network are still connected. No reduction in speed, no problems pinging anything, nothing...It's really only this one Windows machine.

## My setup

- HP Z240 workstation
- Windows 10.0.19041
- WireGuard VPN for work
- ExpressVPN for personal use
- WSL2, with again Ubuntu 20.04
- Connected to home network via WiFi and/or GBit Ethernet
- PiHole DNS server

This makes my network connections look like this:

[image: network connections]

Comment: Did you try updating the drivers?

Comment: @CaldeiraG of the network cards? Yea...well, via Windows Update (no updates available)

Comment: Did you try changing your DNS server to google or other than your ISP?

Comment: @harrymc Yup, tried 8.8.8.8, 1.1.1.1, the PiHole (and all of its DNS options)

Comment: Does your router have a log that you may consult? You may also try to factory reset the router or (better) search for a firmware update. Which model is the router?

Comment: @harrymc hmmm I'll look this info up, but since the other machines on my network show no problems (including Windows 10 machines), a router problem doesn't seem likely...

Comment: @harrymc Huawei HG659b. There's a menu option for "system logs", but nothing shows up when I click there..

Comment: When trying ethernet and wifi, were these two different network adapters in the computer?

Comment: @harrymc ah, uBlock Origin blocking the system logs. Nothing of interest. Firmware is the latest version

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112197/discussion-between-rody-oldenhuis-and-harrymc).